# listings-package custom language delimiter match left-side

Tags: listings

I'm trying to define a new language cli-like interface, but I can not figure out how the use the delimiter to match my prompt.

I want to apply tree different styles to the text. In the example below I have underlined each char with a `~`, `-` or `=` to signal what style group they should belong to.

```
# configure terminal
~ ==================
(config)# json notification host a
--------~ ========================
(something-something)# url http://10.99.10.1:8000/path
---------------------~ ===============================
```

I have been experimenting with this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstdefinelanguage{iCli}
{
  comment=[l]{\%},
  basicstyle=\small,
  keywords={\#},
  keywordstyle=\textbf,
  delim=[s][keywordstyle]{(}{\#}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=iCli]
% This is a comment
# configure terminal
(config)# json notification host a
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

But it does not highlight `#` as a keyword

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to highlight `(config)` and `(something-something)` in red, but not the following `#` or the first `#`. Correct? What color should `#` characters be highlighted in?

Comment: I would like the text before the `#` to be red(or some other color), and then I would like all `#` to be bold, and the other text normal.

Comment: @Jubobs I added a compilable example

Comment: It would also be okay if I could get the complete prompt (from the beginning of the line to `#`) in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit of hacking is required; see below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% the following two packages are for bold typewriter font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beramono}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinelanguage{iCli}{
  comment    = [l]{\%},
  literate   = \#{{\processhash}}1,              %<-- required for bold prompt
  moredelim  = **[is][\processmydelims]{(}{)\#}, %<-- for highlighting (...)#
  basicstyle = \ttfamily,                        %<-- for a nice typewriter font
}

% helper macros
\newcommand\processmydelimsend{}
\newcommand\processmydelims{%
  \renewcommand\processmydelimsend{\textcolor{red}{)}\textbf{\#}\egroup}%
  \bgroup\color{red}(\aftergroup\processmydelimsend%
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\processhash{%
  \ifnum\lst@mode=\lst@Pmode%
    \bfseries%
  \fi
  \#%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=iCli]
# configure terminal
(config)# json notification host a
(something-something)# url http://10.99.10.1:8000/path
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response - it works but I have totally given up on understanding what it does, or why it is needed. I guess that this is what you mean with "A bit of hacking is required" :-)